# JAVA - Is it possible to have Instance variable in a non-static class which is injected at multiple places?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, instance, autowired, final

I have a **non-final** instance variable in my service.
(I have used an instance variable because it is populated in different cases in a single method flow and I don't want to populate it again and again by making it a local variable because it uses a DB call to fetch the value).

Now, this service is injected using `private final` keywords in my constructor.
I observed that this variable stores its value in subsequent API calls.

Is this because the service is injected using the `final` keyword?
And

1. What is the solution? Will using the `private` keyword only resolve the issue?
2. why use `final` at all while injecting a dependency?
3. If using only private keyword will not resolve this issue, How else should I reuse this variable(immutable) across methods used in a single flow? Since it passes by value, initialising it to null in the parent method and then checking it at every instance didn't work. One solution is to create a singleton list but is there a better solution?

Code
Constructor:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Constructor {

    private final Service service;

    public List<Restriction> checkRestrictions(A a, B b) {
        return service.checkRestriction(a, b);
    }
```

Service:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Service {

    private TeamResponseDto originalDetails = null;

    public List<restriction> checkRestriction(A a, B b){
        Restriction r1 = method1();
        Restriction r2 = method2();
        List<Restriction> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(r1);list.add(r2);
        return list;
    }
    private Restriction method1(){
        if(something){
        return new Restriction();
        }
        originalDetails = dbCall();
        return new Restriction(originalDetails);
    }
    private Restriction method2(){
        originalDetails = originalDetails == null ? DBCall() : originalDetails;
        return new Restriction(originalDetails);
    }
}
```

To avoid DB Call in method2, I wrote the above structure.
First time, it works fine.
Second time i.e. fresh thread via a new API call, originalDetails still reflect what it fetched from DB, the first time.

Comment: What framework are you using for dependency injection?

Comment: @bhspencer Spring Boot

Comment: Most injected objects in Spring Boot are single instances. Java keywords won't imply injection, but, anyway, you should post your code and explain where you see that behavior.

Comment: @PeterMmm I have added code. See if it makes sense now

Comment: All final means is that the value/reference held cannot change. Beans by default are singleton scoped meaning that if you request it again and again, you get the same instance.

Comment: You might be able to get away with it if you set the [scope](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes) to request, but typically spring boot services are singletons that get reused across requests, sessions, etc. and they should be stateless. Holding state in instance variables will cause bugs.

Comment: Nit pick.    Your DI is not spring-boot.  It is spring-beans. Spring boot "brings in" : org.springframework:spring-beans. For example (at the time of writing this) ..        Spring Boot 2.7.2 brings in : org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.22

Comment: You may want to look at the discussion about spring bean "scopes" : https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html or newer : https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.x/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes

Answer (score 0):

Very bad idea to to have state in your `Service`. A simple solution is to pass the `originalDetails` as parameter and keep the state of the object in the scope of 1 method call instead of object wide:

```
public class Service {

    public List<Restriction> checkRestriction(A a, B b){
        TeamResponseDto originalDetails = DBCall();
        Restriction r1 = method1(originalDetails);
        Restriction r2 = method2(originalDetails);
        List<Restriction> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(r1);list.add(r2);
        return list;
    }

    private Restriction method1(TeamResponseDto originalDetails){
        if(something){
            return new Restriction();
        }
        return new Restriction(originalDetails);
    }

    private Restriction method2(TeamResponseDto originalDetails){
        return new Restriction(originalDetails);
    }
}
```

Comment: Had this been possible, it would have been very straightforward. 
In actual code, the data required to make the DB call is deduced in method 1 or method 2 when needed to make the DB call. 
Also, there are conditions in method2 as well. DB Call may never be required at all.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate, for now, I have created an empty list in the parent method and passed it as a parameter in the child methods.
Inside the methods, check if the list is empty, fetch the data and populate the list, else, use the value.